# Do Rangers and Hunters get all the abilities listed in the Animal Companion table for Druid?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I want to know if Rangers and Hunters get all the special abilities listed in the [Animal Companion table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions).

Like [Link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Link-Ex-), [Share Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Share-Spells-Ex-), etc.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**  I know it says "druid" in the text on the animal companion table explanations but those other classes say things like "This ability functions like the druid animal companion ability (which is part of the nature bond class feature). The hunter's effective druid level is equal to her hunter level." So anyone with the animal companion ability gets those specific special abilities, it's not "nerfed" for non-druids besides the effective level drop.

Comment: The [Winged Marauder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo---alchemist-archetypes/winged-marauder-alchemist-archetype) Goblin Alchemist Archetype is an example of an exception to this general rule being called out explicitly: "A marauder and his companion don't gain the share spells ability."